# matlab inputParser undefined

Tags: matlab

I defined a matlab function and used `interParser` to make input more flexible.

```
function [a]=fun(s1,varargin)
ip=inputParser;

addParameter(ip,'s2',1);
```

But when I compile the code, I get an error saying

> Undefined function or variable 'inputParser'

I don't know what is wrong. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Your code has "interParser" not "inputParser". Use "inputParser".

Comment: Also, check your version of MATLAB against the docs.

Comment: I'm sorry, I type the wrong code, It should be 'ip=inputParser;' But the error message is correct. The version of My MATLAB is 2017a, but I think all version might suppot 'inputParser'.